# make php open a file with the correct program

Tags: php, file, directory

I have implemented a simple php directory system that let´s me see files and folders. Is there a way to open a file with the correct program, like in windows? for example, if it´s a .doc you click it and it opens in word.

Comment: "Opens" where?  On the server?  On the client?  Please specify what it is you're trying to do and what attempt you've made.

Answer (score 0):

As you may not remember: php is a serverside tool. It is unable to launch applications on the clients computer. You may only provide the doc file for download and probably Firefox (or whatever browser you are using) will open your Word with the file. If you configured it that way.